KMM Ktor Cannot access class 'kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject'
Trying to use JsonObject in a KMM project with Ktor but getting:
Cannot access class 'kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Is something known about this issue?
Ktor version: 2.3.10, Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2

Well ... have you checked your classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies ... ? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization
